# Moving questions under the SEO tag to webmasters.stackexchange.com

Tags: support, migration

My primary interest is search engine optimization. As such, Pro Webmasters is the stack site at which I can be most helpful. However, I follow the SEO tag on StackOverflow as well. Just that tag on StackOverflow has about the same volume of posts of all of Pro Webmasters. About half the questions asked there are not implementation related and would have been better asked on Pro Webmasters. Is there a shortcut I can use to recommend that those questions be moved to Pro Webmasters for StackOverflow? I've been flagging them as "need moderator attention" with a comment that they should be moved. However, very few of them are actually moved, many are closed, even while my flags are marked as "helpful".

(I originally asked this on webmasters meta, but Paul Morriss suggested I ask here instead: [Moving questions TO webmasters](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/945/moving-questions-to-webmasters))

Comment: Nothing gets migrated unless it's off-topic on the source site.

Comment: I tend to flag them as they come in, and only the ones that are off-topic here (not implementation related).   Certainly not the old ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> About half the questions asked there are not implementation related and would have been better asked on Pro Webmasters.

By all means, if the questions being asked here are *off-topic* and would be acceptable on that site, flag them for migration. However, keep these things in mind:

- We *only* migrate things if they are off-topic *here*, not because they are *also* on-topic elsewhere.
- Only questions which are less than 60 days old can be migrated, even by moderators. Even then, if the question is more than a few days old and already has answers (especially accepted), its unlikely to be migrated.
- We don't migrate questions which would likely end up being closed for another reason once it gets to its destination.

Comment: Here are two examples that were closed as off-topic, but which would have gotten good answers on webmasters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988905/will-i-lose-search-ranking-if-i-switch-cloud-provider  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020050/google-does-not-show-the-correct-url  I flagged each of those with requests to move and they were closed instead.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: It could be very possible that moderators between the two sites conversed and decided those questions should not be migrated. I can't tell you the exact thought process the moderators went through in deciding, but neither of those questions look particularly outstanding enough to warrant a migration.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'll continue to flag the questions that don't belong on stack overflow that I recommend to be moved and let the moderators decide whether to close or move them.

Comment: @animuson I'm a webmasters moderator and I'm not aware of any conversation about those questions. The first one linked to was answered by the webmasters highest rep user (who is also a mod). The SEO tag wiki mentions the webmasters site. My opinion is that more good question could get migrated from SO to webmasters, like those two examples, rather than just being closed.